# import f2py extension as 'import mymod.foo'

Tags: python, import, python-sphinx, f2py, autodoc

I've created a Python module from Fortran files with:

```
f2py -c -m mymod file1.f90 file2.f90 file3.f90
```

`file1.f90` contains Fortran modules: `foo`, `bar`, `bar`.
Module `foo` contains functions: `f`,`g`,`h`.

f2py automatically write docstring for function `f`.

`mymod.so` is contained in directory `ROOT`, and I've added `ROOT` in my `PYTHONPATH`.

I can access docstring of `f` function with:

```
import mymod
mymod.foo.f.__doc__
```

I now want write documenation for function `f` using autodoc extension of sphinx:

```
.. autofunction:: mymod.foo.f
```

But it fails with:

```
ImportError: No module named mymod.foo
```

I think sphinx is trying to import like this, which does not work:

```
import mymod.foo
foo.f.__doc__
```

I tried to import a package containing `__init__.py`.

How can I make sphinx find `mymod.foo.f` doctring?

Comment: A function `mymod.foo.f` cannot be anything else than a function inside a `mymod/foo.py` file, right? So an `import mymod.foo;mymod.foo.__doc__` would be right. And there *has* to be an `__init__.py` in the package. So... can you give more setup details?